# HTTP Livestreaming with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ffserver

Some context: I have an MKV file, I am attempting to stream it to http://localhost:8090/test.flv as an flv file.

The stream begins and then immediately ends.

The command I am using is:

```
sudo ffmpeg -re -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 2000k -an -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -g 50 http://localhost:8090/test.flv
```

A breakdown of what I believe these options do incase this post becomes useful for someone else:

```
sudo
```

Run as root

```
ffmpeg
```

The stream command thingy

```
-re
```

Stream in real-time

```
-i input.mkv
```

Input option and path to input file

```
-c:v libx264
```

Use codec libx264 for conversion

```
-maxrate 1000k -bufsize 2000k
```

No idea, some options for conversion, seems to help

```
-an -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb
```

Audio options I think, not sure really. Also seems to help

```
-g 50
```

Still no idea, maybe frame rateframerateframerateframerate?

```
http://localhost:8090/test.flv
```

Output using http protocol to localhost on port 8090 as a file called test.flv

**Anyway the actual issue I have is that it begins to stream for about a second and then immediately ends.**

**The mpeg command result:**

```
ffmpeg version N-80901-gfebc862 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.0
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:02
  Duration: 00:01:32.26, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4432 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High 10), yuv420p10le, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(nor): Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
[libx264 @ 0x2e1c380] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x2e1c380] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x2e1c380] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x2e1c380] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=50 keyint_min=5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=1000 vbv_bufsize=2000 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[flv @ 0x2e3f0a0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Output #0, flv, to 'http://localhost:8090/test.flv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.48.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 1000000/0/0 buffer size: 2000000 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Killed   26 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
```

**The ffserver outputs:**

```
Sat Aug 20 12:40:11 2016 File '/test.flv' not found
Sat Aug 20 12:40:11 2016 [SERVER IP] - - [POST] "/test.flv HTTP/1.1" 404 189
```

**The config file is:**

```
#Sample ffserver configuration file

# Port on which the server is listening. You must select a different
# port from your standard HTTP web server if it is running on the same
# computer.
Port 8090

# Address on which the server is bound. Only useful if you have
# several network interfaces.
BindAddress 0.0.0.0

# Number of simultaneous HTTP connections that can be handled. It has
# to be defined *before* the MaxClients parameter, since it defines the
# MaxClients maximum limit.
MaxHTTPConnections 2000

# Number of simultaneous requests that can be handled. Since FFServer
# is very fast, it is more likely that you will want to leave this high
# and use MaxBandwidth, below.
MaxClients 1000

# This the maximum amount of kbit/sec that you are prepared to
# consume when streaming to clients.
MaxBandwidth 1000

# Access log file (uses standard Apache log file format)
# '-' is the standard output.
CustomLog -

# Suppress that if you want to launch ffserver as a daemon.
#NoDaemon


##################################################################
# Definition of the live feeds. Each live feed contains one video
# and/or audio sequence coming from an ffmpeg encoder or another
# ffserver. This sequence may be encoded simultaneously with several
# codecs at several resolutions.

<Feed feed1.ffm>

ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255

# You must use 'ffmpeg' to send a live feed to ffserver. In this
# example, you can type:
#
#ffmpeg http://localhost:8090/test.ffm

# ffserver can also do time shifting. It means that it can stream any
# previously recorded live stream. The request should contain:
# "http://xxxx?date=[YYYY-MM-DDT][[HH:]MM:]SS[.m...]".You must specify
# a path where the feed is stored on disk. You also specify the
# maximum size of the feed, where zero means unlimited. Default:
# File=/tmp/feed_name.ffm FileMaxSize=5M
File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 200m

# You could specify
# ReadOnlyFile /saved/specialvideo.ffm
# This marks the file as readonly and it will not be deleted or updated.

# Specify launch in order to start ffmpeg automatically.
# First ffmpeg must be defined with an appropriate path if needed,
# after that options can follow, but avoid adding the http:// field
#Launch ffmpeg

# Only allow connections from localhost to the feed.
    ACL allow 127.0.0.1

</Feed>


##################################################################
# Now you can define each stream which will be generated from the
# original audio and video stream. Each format has a filename (here
# 'test1.mpg'). FFServer will send this stream when answering a
# request containing this filename.

<Stream test1.mpg>

# coming from live feed 'feed1'
Feed feed1.ffm

# Format of the stream : you can choose among:
# mpeg       : MPEG-1 multiplexed video and audio
# mpegvideo  : only MPEG-1 video
# mp2        : MPEG-2 audio (use AudioCodec to select layer 2 and 3 codec)
# ogg        : Ogg format (Vorbis audio codec)
# rm         : RealNetworks-compatible stream. Multiplexed audio and video.
# ra         : RealNetworks-compatible stream. Audio only.
# mpjpeg     : Multipart JPEG (works with Netscape without any plugin)
# jpeg       : Generate a single JPEG image.
# asf        : ASF compatible streaming (Windows Media Player format).
# swf        : Macromedia Flash compatible stream
# avi        : AVI format (MPEG-4 video, MPEG audio sound)
Format mpeg

# Bitrate for the audio stream. Codecs usually support only a few
# different bitrates.
AudioBitRate 32

# Number of audio channels: 1 = mono, 2 = stereo
AudioChannels 2

# Sampling frequency for audio. When using low bitrates, you should
# lower this frequency to 22050 or 11025. The supported frequencies
# depend on the selected audio codec.
AudioSampleRate 44100

# Bitrate for the video stream
VideoBitRate 64

# Ratecontrol buffer size
VideoBufferSize 40

# Number of frames per second
VideoFrameRate 3

# Size of the video frame: WxH (default: 160x128)
# The following abbreviations are defined: sqcif, qcif, cif, 4cif, qqvga,
# qvga, vga, svga, xga, uxga, qxga, sxga, qsxga, hsxga, wvga, wxga, wsxga,
# wuxga, woxga, wqsxga, wquxga, whsxga, whuxga, cga, ega, hd480, hd720,
# hd1080
VideoSize hd1080

# Transmit only intra frames (useful for low bitrates, but kills frame rate).
#VideoIntraOnly

# If non-intra only, an intra frame is transmitted every VideoGopSize
# frames. Video synchronization can only begin at an intra frame.
VideoGopSize 12

# More MPEG-4 parameters
# VideoHighQuality
# Video4MotionVector

# Choose your codecs:
#AudioCodec mp2
#VideoCodec mpeg1video

# Suppress audio
#NoAudio

# Suppress video
#NoVideo

#VideoQMin 3
#VideoQMax 31

# Set this to the number of seconds backwards in time to start. Note that
# most players will buffer 5-10 seconds of video, and also you need to allow
# for a keyframe to appear in the data stream.
#Preroll 15

# ACL:

# You can allow ranges of addresses (or single addresses)
ACL ALLOW localhost

# You can deny ranges of addresses (or single addresses)
#ACL DENY <first address> 

# You can repeat the ACL allow/deny as often as you like. It is on a per
# stream basis. The first match defines the action. If there are no matches,
# then the default is the inverse of the last ACL statement.
#
# Thus 'ACL allow localhost' only allows access from localhost.
# 'ACL deny 1.0.0.0 1.255.255.255' would deny the whole of network 1 and
# allow everybody else.

</Stream>


##################################################################
# Example streams


# Multipart JPEG

#<Stream test.mjpg>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format mpjpeg
#VideoFrameRate 2
#VideoIntraOnly
#NoAudio
#Strict -1
#</Stream>


# Single JPEG

#<Stream test.jpg>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format jpeg
#VideoFrameRate 2
#VideoIntraOnly
##VideoSize 352x240
#NoAudio
#Strict -1
#</Stream>


# Flash

#<Stream test.swf>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format swf
#VideoFrameRate 2
#VideoIntraOnly
#NoAudio
#</Stream>


# ASF compatible

<Stream test.asf>
Feed feed1.ffm
Format asf
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoSize 352x240
VideoBitRate 256
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoGopSize 30
AudioBitRate 64
StartSendOnKey
</Stream>


# MP3 audio

#<Stream test.mp3>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format mp2
#AudioCodec mp3
#AudioBitRate 64
#AudioChannels 1
#AudioSampleRate 44100
#NoVideo
#</Stream>


# Ogg Vorbis audio

#<Stream test.ogg>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Title "Stream title"
#AudioBitRate 64
#AudioChannels 2
#AudioSampleRate 44100
#NoVideo
#</Stream>


# Real with audio only at 32 kbits

#<Stream test.ra>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format rm
#AudioBitRate 32
#NoVideo
#NoAudio
#</Stream>


# Real with audio and video at 64 kbits

#<Stream test.rm>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format rm
#AudioBitRate 32
#VideoBitRate 128
#VideoFrameRate 25
#VideoGopSize 25
#NoAudio
#</Stream>


##################################################################
# A stream coming from a file: you only need to set the input
# filename and optionally a new format. Supported conversions:
#    AVI -> ASF

#<Stream file.rm>
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/tlive.rm"
#NoAudio
#</Stream>

#<Stream file.asf>
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/test.asf"
#NoAudio
#Author "Me"
#Copyright "Super MegaCorp"
#Title "Test stream from disk"
#Comment "Test comment"
#</Stream>


##################################################################
# RTSP examples
#
# You can access this stream with the RTSP URL:
#   rtsp://localhost:5454/test1-rtsp.mpg
#
# A non-standard RTSP redirector is also created. Its URL is:
#   http://localhost:8090/test1-rtsp.rtsp

#<Stream test1-rtsp.mpg>
#Format rtp
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/test1.mpg"
#</Stream>


# Transcode an incoming live feed to another live feed,
# using libx264 and video presets

#<Stream live.h264>
#Format rtp
#Feed feed1.ffm
#VideoCodec libx264
#VideoFrameRate 24
#VideoBitRate 100
#VideoSize 480x272
#AVPresetVideo default
#AVPresetVideo baseline
#AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
#
#AudioCodec libfaac
#AudioBitRate 32
#AudioChannels 2
#AudioSampleRate 22050
#AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
#</Stream>

##################################################################
# SDP/multicast examples
#
# If you want to send your stream in multicast, you must set the
# multicast address with MulticastAddress. The port and the TTL can
# also be set.
#
# An SDP file is automatically generated by ffserver by adding the
# 'sdp' extension to the stream name (here
# http://localhost:8090/test1-sdp.sdp). You should usually give this
# file to your player to play the stream.
#
# The 'NoLoop' option can be used to avoid looping when the stream is
# terminated.

#<Stream test1-sdp.mpg>
#Format rtp
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/test1.mpg"
#MulticastAddress 224.124.0.1
#MulticastPort 5000
#MulticastTTL 16
#NoLoop
#</Stream>


##################################################################
# Special streams

# Server status

<Stream stat.html>
Format status

# Only allow local people to get the status
ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255

#FaviconURL http://pond1.gladstonefamily.net:8080/favicon.ico
</Stream>


# Redirect index.html to the appropriate site

<Redirect index.html>
URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>


#http://www.ffmpeg.org/
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I will do my best draw a picture of the best answer based on their username.

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's probably far beyond my ability at the moment.
However I had some success using [Mist server](https://github.com/DDVTECH/mistserver/) instead

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a feed named test.flv in your config file, just one named feed1.ffm.

Try this command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 2000k -an -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -g 50 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

Another option would be to change your ffserver.conf file.

-g 50 means, that the GOP size is 50. You can define the framerate with -framerate